# How to do 3D Object Tracking on Web (PWA)?

Tags: javascript, web, augmented-reality, progressive-web-apps, vuforia

Since it is possible to have AR and 2D image recognition in a web browser with help of tools like WebXR, WebVR, Argon.js, AR.js, three.ar.js, ..., I wanted to know if there is a .js lib or a tool that can help me do 3d Object tracking, like Vuforia 3D object tracking in Native Android and Unity Apps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:
a littel cool paper for Rapid Object Detection using a Boosted Cascade of Simple Features:
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf 
or some good info on this page: 
http://techslides.com/object-detection-with-html5-getusermedia